# Apply jQuery function to each newly created (dynamic) element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button that creates a dynamic `textarea` field with a unique `id`. Each time a new element is created, I want jQuery to trigger on those dynamic textarea fields.

I tried the `.on('click')` method and it doesn't run the jQuery on the dynamic element unless the button that generates them is pushed twice. So that won't work. Secondly, when I create a second dynamic textarea field, it doesn't work at all, even if I click the button twice.

```
    jQuery('button').on('click', function() {
        var dynamicElement = jQuery('.parentclass').find('textarea').attr('id');

//countChar is part of a function not displayed here (works fine).

    countChar(jQuery('#'+dynamicElement).get(0));

//This code below never seems to apply itself to any dynamic textarea fields except for
//the first one. It needs to apply itself to all of them and trigger each time a new
//dynamic textarea field is created.

    jQuery('#'+dynamicElement).keyup(function() {
        countChar(this);
    })

    });
```

How would I go about making this work?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the function countChar (it adds a character counter and limits the characters too).

**Function**

```
function countChar(val) {
    var allowed_length = 700; // character count limit here
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= allowed_length) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, allowed_length);
        jQuery(".chars[data-textarea="+val.id+"]").text(0);
    } else {
        jQuery(".chars[data-textarea="+val.id+"]").text(allowed_length - len);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="parentclass">

<td class="label">
    <label>
        Custom Title
    </label>
    <span class="field-instructions">
        Please enter the content of this field.
        Remaining: <span class="chars" data-textarea="dynamic-textarea-1"></span>
    </span>
</td>

<td>
    <div class="inner">
        <textarea rows="4" id="dynamic-textarea-1" class="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can include `html` ? , `js` where _"a button that creates a dynamic textarea field with a unique id"_ ?

Comment: What does `countChar ` do? Where is the function that creates the dynElement? More code please.

Comment: maybe something like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/z7y2hp36/1/ ? I'm kind of guessing what exactly you need, as you didn't provide any html.

Comment: I added more information for you guys, hope that helps.

Comment: @mkaminsky I tried your solution, while it made sense. It still didn't work. I still needed to hit the button twice for it to apply the jQuery to the new textarea element.

Comment: @Bryan The answers in that page didn't work for me.

Comment: where are the multiple `textarea`s? Are you adding more of them?

Comment: @mkaminsky The HTML I edited into my question is the HTML that is created when the button is pushed. As you can see, it includes a textarea field. I have set it so a max of 5 additional custom fields may be entered by a user.

Comment: What `.attr('id')` does is get the first element in the set's ID.  Since that will always be the first `textarea` added, it will only ever get that first textarea's ID.  If you want the last one created, maybe try selecting `$('.parentClass textarea:last-of-type')`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a variable ex.  var x = document.getElementById("name of element");  then change whatever property you want, any other events needs to bee outside of the click event so it could trigger on its own. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I'm still learning. Is there any way you can give me a code example with my jQuery?

Comment: Lets imagine that your method create an element <textarea id="dynamicallyCreated"> </textarea>, in your method countchar what you really want to do is set a property of that element, for the amount of char input in a textarea tag you could use (maxlength), therefore you will do the following,  x = document.getElementById(dynamicElement ).maxlenght =  50;